# Ionic captured audio upload to Firebase Storage

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic, audio, blob

I am trying to upload to Firebase Storage audio captured using MediaCapture, converting the MediaFile to blob, but when I read the file using readAsArrayBuffer or readAsDataUrl the buffer that returns is empty. I tried a lot of ways to do this but I didn't resolve it. Here is the newest code. Thanks!

```
    this.mediaCapture.captureAudio().then(res => {
      try{
        this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(res[0].localURL).then(entry => {
          this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(entry.nativeURL.substr(0, entry.nativeURL.lastIndexOf('/')), entry.name).then((buffer: any) => {
            let blob: any = new Blob([buffer], {
              type: 'audio/mp3'
            });
            this.angularFireStorage.ref(refURL).put(blob);
          }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
        })
      } catch(error){
        presentToast(error);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding: `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to androidManifest.xml.